# How to set scheduler cron times in PST for Heroku servers given they use UTC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, cron, resque, resque-scheduler

Since servers on Heroku run under UTC time, how do you set the cron time to run at 3am PST daily? Before you recommend the built in Heroku scheduler, I would like to keep everything inside of Resque. Also, it would be cool to leave the server time as UTC.

```
ImportClass:
  description: 'Import Class'
  custom_job_class: 'Class::ImportClass'
  cron: '0 3 * * *'
  queue: high
```

Comment: Can't you let it run at 23hrs UTC instead?

Comment: What is the difference? How do you correlate cron times to PST for example?

Comment: cron times are in the timezone of the server. Assuming you have servers in Europe, you can configure cron times accordingly

Comment: From reading the docs it states the servers are all using UTC.  Again, is the only way to change the time zone of the box or is there a way to keep UTC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TZ ENV variable can be added via the Heroku dashboard if you prefer. Open your app's dashboard and navigate to the 'settings' tab, then under 'config variables' click the 'reveal config vars' button. You will then be able to add TZ = America/Chicago (or whatever timezone you need).

Then set the cron accordingly

FYI: List of available tz zones are https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: Thank you so much for the great discussion.  Again, is the only way to change the time zone of the box or is there a way to keep UTC?  I will most likely change the timezone on the box, but I was curious.